# Reveal secp256k1 public key on Babylonnet

Tags: reveal, tezos-signer

Currently, dose Tezos support secp256k1 key?

I tried to broadcast a transaction to reveal public key for a secp256k1 key.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net/injection/operation -d '"466ab4f35ee8657c2b632394215e7243bbb11942ac75bc6d4c5dc716655c38446b01396167e3f38c31008b38557f9feedf3f54745bad8827f1de08d08c01ac020002f746e7d62a6c0cc12936673bbb1f23e1938b85f60e30fd2b1e8525bb2844ded0f729c01136da6abe7ffeb9632e0a475eb68b7fdf0be82d862afb9b6f1cce4dc768678994e7841c28b4732190912d92b4f80b5ae0935470bbbb07cae1bc6d6a8b"'
```

I always got this error:

```
[
    {
        "kind": "permanent",
        "id": "node.prevalidation.parse_error"
    }
]
```

It seems that the tezos node assupe that the public key length should be 32. If the delete the last byte of secp256k1 public key, then the parse_error will disappear.

Did anyone have successfully revealed secp256k1 public key?

Answer (score 3):

Questions was solved in another channel (https://t.me/TezosDevelopers).

Answer from BakingBad:

"Tezos supports pubkey revealing for tz2 addresses. You just need to use correct message Tag.

You can do that, for secp256k1
https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/p2p.html#public-key-determined-from-data-8-bit-tag

I guess, you set the incorrect `Tag`"

Answer (score 2):

Tezos support secp256k1 key, but it uses the compressed format of public keys which is 33 bytes long.